# ChartJS a bug/feature when bar overlap one another

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a problem with ChartJS. Some times, especially in the night the bug appears...

[image]

As you can see the bug creates big gap between labels and bar becomes wide. I don't know, maybe it's a feature, but I don't want that feature. Maybe someone had such problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you provide your code ? On either a SO snippet or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Tektiv, I can only add some parts of code. For example provide chart options

Comment: Yeah show the options that will help